# OutputSteam.write(int) only writes 1 byte to file?

Tags: java, io

Hello I have the following code:

```
int i=12345;
DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Raw.txt"));
dos.write(i);
dos.close();
System.out.println(new File("Raw.txt").length());
```

The file size is being reported as 1 byte. Why is it not 4 bytes when an integer is 4 bytes long?

Thanks

Comment: See [DataOutputStream write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(int))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the [`DataOutputStream.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write%28int%29) method takes an `int` argument, it actually only writes the bottom 8 bits of that argument.  So you actually wrote only one byte ... and hence the file is one byte long.

If you want to write the entire `int` you should use the `writeInt(int)` method.

---

The underlying reason for this strangeness is (I believe) that the `write(int)` method is defined to be consistent with `OutputStream.write(int)` which in turn defined to be consistent with `InputStream.read()`.  `InputStream.read()` reads a `byte` and returns it as an `int` ... with the value `-1` used to indicate the end-of-stream condition.

Answer (score 8):

Because you only wrote one byte to it. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write%28int%29) for `DataOutputStream.write(int).` It writes a `byte,` not an `int.`